# With Python Click, how to make it NOT print "[OPTIONS]" in usage text for commands that have no options?

Tags: python, python-click

I'm using Python Click. I have a few options for the program, but one of my commands have no option of its own. So to use that command, the user would type in something like this:

```
python script.py [OPTIONS] cmd argument
```

but by default, the usage text for all commands is something like this:

```
Usage: script.py cmd [OPTIONS] argument
```

I think it's very misleading, because it looks like the options should be placed after "cmd", which would generate "Error: No such option". I'd like the usage text to be something like this:

```
Usage: script.py [OPTIONS] cmd argument
```

at minimum, like this:

```
Usage: script.py cmd argument
```

What's the best way to do this ?